# PSpice OrCAD simulation

Tags: pspice

I want to get an impedance vs frequency graph for a capacitor in AC sweep analysis. I saw that there is an 'Impedance(1,2)' as shown in this picture in the Modify Trace window under Plot window templates:

[image: Modify Trace window under Plot window templates]

Can someone tell me how to use this and also if I can get Impedance vs. Frequency graph using this? If you know any other way to get the required graph please do share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impedance(Voltage,Current)

So for instance if you are trying to plot the impedance of a capacitor C1 vs. frequency, you would type in something like:

Impedance(V(C1:1), I(C1))

It is essentially just the same as typing in V/I manually, e.g. V(C1:1)/I(C1)